# upload images faster to firebase storage using the Admin SDK with Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I wrote a short program where I can upload images to firebase storage with python:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage
import os

cred = credentials.Certificate("certificate.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, { 'storageBucket' : 'AppName.appspot.com'})

bucket = storage.bucket()
directory = '/Users/name/Desktop/TestOrdner/'

for foldername in os.listdir(directory):
    if str(foldername[0]) != '.':       
         for image in os.listdir(directory + foldername):
             blob = bucket.blob(f'{foldername}/{image}')
             imagePath = directory + foldername + '/' + image
             blob.upload_from_filename(imagePath)
```

Currently I have one folder. Inside the folder there are five other folders. Each of the folder contains four images. To upload this to firebase storage it takes 15 seconds. For example I would like to upload 150 images, it would like to take ages. Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: Upload speed to Firebase Storage could be affected by many factors including file size and local network conditions. The [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas) provides information such as ‘Establishing baseline performance’ and ‘Improving upload performance’ that you could use to diagnose and improve the performance.